# customizing access inherited functions

Tags: c#, java, c++, oop

with C#, java or c++ ...

we have the following classes

```
class A
{
  void x(){y();}
  void y(){}
}

class B :A
{
   void y(){};
   void a(){x();}
}

//in main or somewhere 
B b=new B();
b.a();
```

when function "a" is called it will call the base "x" function
the question is, which function the function  "x" will call (base y() / derived y() ) ?
and how can we control which one to invoke !!

note: take the concept, i know that the three languages are not the same.

Comment: Please pick one language; the syntax and semantics are different for each.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I disagree, the question is clear - and it is quite obvious how to translate the above into each of the three languages.

Comment: Mr. @OliCharlesworth just take the concept, i know the three languages are not the same but who can write (C++/JAVA/C#) can read and understand the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming you meant to declare everything as public, and use appropriate syntax for each language)

In Java and C# it will call B::y.

In C++ it will call A::y.

In C++, If you had of declared A::y as **virtual** it will call B::y instead.

Implementing static dispatch (A::y) is more performant than dynamic dispatch (B::y), so the option is left open in C++ to choose between them (virtual or non-virtual).  For Java and C# the language designers decided to keep it simple and only allow dynamic dispatch, so there is not way in those two languages to do static dispatch (A::y).

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't valid C++, but if you said `B * b = new B; b->a();`, then `A::y()` would be called because it is not `virtual`. In Java, *all* non-static member functions are implicitly virtual, so `B::y()` gets called there.

Your question is very misleading, by the way, since "access" is something totally different (relating to `public` and `private` etc.). For that matter, the code wouldn't compile in any language because `B::a()` is not `public`.

Comment: Thanks my friend for your answer, but what i wrote is the concept and anyone who can write (C++/JAVA/C#) can read and understand the code.

Answer (score 2):

What this code sample will do is very dependent on the language you are using here.  Your question mentions C# / C++ and Java here and they will differ for the above basic pattern.

C# and C++ are fairly similar here in that functions aren't virtual by default.  Hence the invocation of `x()` in `x()` will refer to `A::x`. In Java though methods are virtual by default hence it will refer to either `A::y` or `B::y` depending on the actual type of `this`.

Here is the sample in all 3 languages to make `y()` be a virtual invocation

C++

```
class A {
public:
  void x(){ y(); }
  virtual void y(){}
};

class B : public A {
public:
  // virtual not needed here but nice
  virtual void y() { }; 
  void a() { x(); }
};


B* b = new B();
b->a();
```

C#

```
class A {
  public void x(){ y(); }
  public virtual void y(){}
}

class B : public A {
  public overrides void y() { }; 
  public void a() { x(); }
};


B b = new B();
b.a();
```

Java

```
class A {
  public void x(){ y(); }
  public void y(){}
}

class B : inherits A {
  public void y() { }; 
  public void a() { x(); }
};

B b = new B();
b.a();
```